# Ruby: What game library is best/simplest for 2D arcades/platformers?

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I want to create simple arcade on **Ruby**. I used **GOSU** some time, and then I find many game libraries for ruby: **RubyGame**, **Chingu** ....

What library is best for game development, and why?

Comment: Well they say this type of questions is forbidden ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for you to decide based on what exactly you will implement https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/game_libraries

Answer (score 3):

[Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org) is the most popular (and actively maintained) library for writing 2D games in Ruby. It has an underlying C++ library that it uses to improve performance and interact with the underlying display rendering libraries like OpenGL.

I'm also working on a gem that will make it easier to write real arcade games in Ruby. In the mean time, you may be interested in using a MAME compatible arcade controller. I wrote a gem that provides the [common MAME keyboard input mappings for Gosu](https://github.com/ruby-rcade/rcade-controls).

There is also a gem called [GameBox](https://github.com/shawn42/gamebox) which uses Gosu behind the scenes. GameBox attempts to abstract many of the common game boilerplate so that you are left with writing the "business logic" of your game.